# common function for creating string to json with gson android

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

I want to create a function that can convert string to JSON with Gson like I'll pass response JSON to that function or the function will return me an object 
for example.

```
fun convertJsonToModel(response:string,/*class that i want to convert*/){
  val gson = Gson()
  gson.fromJson(jsonString, /*class that i pass i args*/)
  return /* same class object that i pass in args*/
}

I want to use like this

var model1 = convertJsonToModel(response,Model1.class)
var model2 = convertJsonToModel(response,Model2.class)
var model3 = convertJsonToModel(response,Model3.class)
```

I don't know how to pass a class in function args and then return with the converted object 
please help

Comment: which is already there in Gson https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Gson's `fromJson()`:

```
val gson = Gson()
gson.fromJson(jsonString, ModelClass.class)
```

If you *want* your common function as a wrapper around this:

```
fun <T> convertJsonToModel(jsonString: String, modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    val gson = Gson()
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, modelClass)
}
```

Comment: i want to make a common function for convert this

Comment: Why not use this method itself instead of creating your own? It is already inbuilt in Gson

Answer (score 0):

Moreover for this, you can create an Extension function too as below,

```
fun <T> String.toObject(targetClass: Class<T>): T {
val gson = Gson()
return gson.fromJson(this, targetClass)
}
```